# CSS for hiding a HTML element, keeping its width and height?

Tags: html, css

I need a CSS snippet for hiding a HTML `<div class="my">` (with quite a lot of contents, including text and other divs), but still reserving space for it. Is there something better or faster than `div.my{opacity:0;}`?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

```
visibility: hidden
```

This will hide the element from the page but retain its place in the layout.

Answer (score -10):

use document.getElementById("my").style.display = "none";
do not user visibility it only hide element but in display it remove the space acquired by element.

Comment: OP wants to preserve the space it occupies